# Are there ASCII generators for ERD diagrams?

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

Are there any ASCII generators for ERD diagrams (perhaps that fit well within markup syntax)?

For example, that could generate something like this:

```
 ---------
 |  Hai  |
 ---------
     |
     |
    /|\
 ---------         ------------          ---------
 |  Foo  |-------< |  FooBar  | >------- |  Bar  |
 ---------         ------------          ---------
    \|/
     |
     |
 ---------
 |  Bai  |
 ---------
```

Comment: You could also use Graphviz using the DOT language to generate SVG and PNG diagrams. Though it's not ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

I think this link might be helpfull: http://asciiflow.com/

Comment: I had checked that out, but it doesn't appear to generate relationships that show 1:M or N:M, unless I am missing something. The arrow key is as close as it gets but I prefer the crows-feet syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mermaidjs](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/entityRelationshipDiagram) in markdown files to represent ER diagrams. It's not ASCII, but having it in markdown may suit your use-case.

It supported by both [GitHub](https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/tools-and-tips/mermaid/) and most IDEs out there.